# how to convert a symbol into a string and vice versa in CLIPS

Tags: clips

how to convert a symbol into a string and vice versa in CLIPS, I tried looking into the documentation but did not help.

Also are there any functions to convert strings to integers?

Are the set of functions to convert between data types in CLIPS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CLIPS> (str-cat red)
"red"
CLIPS> (sym-cat "red")
red
CLIPS> (str-cat 17)
"17"
CLIPS> (string-to-field "17")
17
CLIPS> (integer 17.3)
17
CLIPS> (float 17)
17.0
CLIPS> (round 17.3)
17
CLIPS> (explode$ "a b c")
(a b c)
CLIPS> (implode$ (create$ a b c))
"a b c"
CLIPS>
```

Comment: thank you Gary, what does string-to-field do? remaining all I understood.

Comment: From section 12.3.12 of the Basic Programming Guide: The string-to-field function parses a string and converts its contents to a primitive data type. Essentially calling string-to-field with its string argument is equivalent to calling the read function and manually typing the contents of the string argument or reading it from a file.